# How can I compile newest VLCJ using Netbeans 7.2?

Tags: java, netbeans, java-me, netbeans-7

I don't have much knowledge about Java programming and I want to use VLCJ for my old phone. I downloaded the latest vlcj-player-master but having problem with compiling it. I'm getting this error:

> COMPILATION ERROR :
>
> ---
>
> Failure executing javac, but could not parse the error:
>
> javac: invalid target release: 1.8
>
> Usage: javac
>
> use -help for a list of possible options
>
> 1 error

Here's the platform on which I'm trying to do:

- Windows XP SP2 x86 (Virtual machine)
- JDK 7u2
- DirectX 9.0c
- Sony Ericsson Java ME SDK for CLDC
- Netbeans 7.2

I can compile the projects and run on my phone without problem with this configuration:

[image]

However I can't find these settings in the properties of project I downloaded.

How can I compile VLCJ to run on my phone?

**EDIT:** Here's the full log output: http://sudrap.org/paste/text/619432/

Comment: vlcj-player requires Java 1.8, I'm guessing your limited Java ME only supports Java 1.6. So your only option really is to compile vlcj-player against Java 1.6 and fix all the incompatibilities. I'll be amazed if vlcj actually works on your phone. You need VLC on there too, have you done that?

Comment: hi, thanks for your answer. where must VLC be? what's the difference between vlc and vlcj? I thought VLCJ is sort of VLC which runs apart from it, am I right?
otherwise I need vlc sources in order to compile vlcj, I guess.. I haven't done that.

Comment: vlcj is a Java binding/framework for LibVLC. As such it requires the native LibVLC binaries to be installed on your target platform. Since in your case this is for a phone, probably you need some special build of VLC for your phone CPU architecture (I have no idea about this really) if it is even possible at all. I think you have some other problems in store to be honest, this is going to be a difficult project if it's even possible.